# Finding $f(x)$ from integral equations

Tags: calculus

> If $f$ is a continuous function such that 
>   $$ \int_0^x f(t) dt = xe^{2x}+\int_0^x e^{-t}f(t) dt $$
>   for all $x$, find an explicit formula for $f$.

I started this problem by differentiating both sides with respect to $x$, getting 
$$f(x) = e^{2x}(1+2x)+e^{-t}f(x).$$
Solving this for $f(x)$ gives $$f(x)=\frac{e^{2x}(1+2x)}{1-e^{-x}}.$$
So my main question is did I do this properly? My second question would then have to be is there an easier way to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: IMO, this is a pretty simple way to solving it.  Straight forward easy.

Comment: Agreed - just remember to mention any necessary/sufficient conditions when dividing (i.e. is $1-e^{-x}=0$? If so can you say for which $x\in \mathbb{R}$ this $f(x)$ is valid for?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct.

Another simple way is to unify the integrals:

$$\int_0^x\ f(t)\left(1 - e^{-t}\right)\ \text{d}t = xe^{2x}$$

Then differentiate with respect to $x$ and $t$ (the second term and the first one respectively), and you will get the same result you got.