# Finding $f(x)$ from integral equation

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have this problem:

Find a contnuous function $f$ such that:

$$\int_0^x f(t)\,dt = (x-1)e^{2x} + \int_0^x e^{-t} f(t)\,dt$$
 and it's required to find $f(x)$ so
$$ \int_0^x f(t)\,dt  -  \int_0^x e^{-t} f(t)\,dt= (x-1)e^{2x} $$
here I differentiated both sides and factor $f(x)$ on the left
$$ f(x)\cdot (1-e^{-x})= 2(x-1)e^{2x}+e^{2x}$$
$$f(x)= \frac{2(x-1)e^{2x}+e^{2x}}{(1-e^{-x})}$$
but the answer appointed is 
$$f(x)= \frac{(1-2x)e^{2x}}{(e^{-x}-1)}$$
did I mess up somewhere or am I lacking some algebra work here?
here is a similar question alredy answered [Finding $f(x)$ from integral equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927171/finding-fx-from-integral-equations)

Comment: After differentiation 8and applying the fundamental theorem) your $t$ should be $x$ (this is also wrong in the appointed answer). Apart from that, factor out the common $e^{2x}$ in th enumerator.

Comment: Your answer and the “appointed” answer look exactly the same to me.

Comment: How are these answers different?

Comment: No reaction from the OP, 2 hours later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers are equal, multiply both denominator and numerator with -1, expand the parenthesis in the numerator add up and factorise again.